# swipe jquery accordion to expand instead of clicking

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

How can I drag an accordion to expand it instead of clicking? I am trying to use it on a mobile website.

The effect that is trying to be achieved is when I drag the first section up it shows the content then when I pull the second section up it hide the old stuff and shows the new stuff.

This is an example of the accordion with out the dragging part.
http://tympanus.net/Development/VerticalSlidingAccordion/example3.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using https://jgestures.codeplex.com/ to achieve this? You should be able to register a swipe event on the accordion.